# Express JS with MySQL Global handling the error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Hi i want to ask about the ExpressJS with MySQL. What is the correct way to handle the error globally when there is error in query using MySQL?

Example error:

> /Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
>           throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>           ^
>
> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:356:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
>       at ServerResponse.json (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
>       at Query._callback (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/src/routes/foodRoutes.js:166:19)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:88:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
>       at Query.OkPacket (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:72:10)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (/Users/stevanuswijaya/yummy-mummy-server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

This is my route in foodRoutes.js:

```
foodRouter.route("/add/food").post(function(req, res, next) {
      var food = req.body.food;
      query =
        "INSERT INTO `food`" +
        "(`food_name`," +
        "`food_category`," +
        "`food_image`," +
        "`price`," +
        "`food_kind`," +
        "`nutrition`," +
        "`calories`," +
        "`user_id`," +
        "`favorite`) " +
        " VALUES( " +
        "'" +
        food.food_name +
        "'" +
        ", " +
        food.food_category +
        ", " +
        "'" +
        food.food_image +
        "'" +
        ", " +
        food.price +
        ", " +
        "'" +
        food.food_kind +
        "'" +
        ", " +
        food.nutrition +
        ", " +
        food.calories +
        ", " +
        food.user_id +
        ", " +
        "'" +
        food.favorite +
        "'" +
        ") ";
      console.log(query);
      //console.log(queryFood);

      connection.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log(err.code);
        return next(err);
      });

      connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
        }
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
          if (err) {
            connection.rollback(function() {
              if (err) {
                return next(err);
              }
            });
          }

          connection.commit(function(err) {
            console.log("Commited");
            if (err) {
              console.log("ERROR");
              connection.rollback(function() {
                console.log("Dinext");
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
              });
            } else if (rows) {
              if (rows.affectedRows) {
                res.status(200).json({
                  status: "success",
                  message: "Inserted one food with food_name " + food.food_name,
                  food_id: rows.insertId
                });
              }
            } else {
              res.json([]);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

And this is my app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var port = 4200;
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require('method-override');


// Required application specific custom router module
var userRouter = require("./src/routes/userRoutes");
var foodRouter = require("./src/routes/foodRoutes");
var placeRouter = require("./src/routes/placeRoutes");
var groupRouter = require("./src/routes/groupRoutes");
var glyphRouter = require("./src/routes/glyphRoutes");

// Use middlewares to set view engine and post json data to the server

//Error Handler
var clientErrorHandler = function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Something failed!' })
  } else {
    next(err)
  }
};

var errorHandler = function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.log(err);
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err)
  }
  res.status(500)
  res.render('error', { error: err })
}

var logErrors = function  (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  next(err)
}

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(methodOverride())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logErrors);
app.use(clientErrorHandler);
app.use(errorHandler);

app.use("/users", userRouter);
app.use("/foods", foodRouter);
app.use("/places", placeRouter);
app.use("/groups", groupRouter);
app.use("/glyphs", glyphRouter);


// Start the server
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: ", port);
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello express");
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to when there is something error in mysql/query, the query and error is logged and the node server is not crashed. Now with current code, the server will crash when there is error in the query. I have try using the error handler and next method in the route but the error still happen. I also have try change route parameter to (err, req, res, and next) but the method is doesn't work. I don't want to only handle the error is only from my front end validation (using react). I want to handle the error also from my server side. Please help. Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried to use global error handlers for node? https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception and https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection

Comment: Thank you i already try the process on uncaughtexception, now the server is not crashed. I will learn about it later. Can you give reference or example for logging the error in server side using Node.js?

Comment: The node.js documentation provides pretty good examples: process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  ....
}); process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});

Comment: Ok i will read it, thank you